# Closing an InputStream

Tags: java, android

I have an InputStream that gets passed to an InputSource:

```
int resID = getResources().getIdentifier("c" + getCfrFile(), "raw", getPackageName());  
InputStream ins  = getResources().openRawResource(resID); 
InputSource xmlSource = new InputSource(ins);   

xmlTableRowLoader = new AcmTableRowLoader(handler, xmlSource, this, pathBuilder(false), "title");
```

How do I properly close() the InputStream? When I try to close it:

```
ins.Close();
```

I get an java.lang.NullPointerException because the stream gets closed before the "xmlSource" is finished with it. Also the object "xmlTableRowLoader" extends Thread.

Comment: What is/does `AcmTableRowLoader`? Do you have javadoc for it? What does it say about its handling of the InputSource parameter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That depends on how AcmTableRowLoader is using it. If it is only using it in its constructor, which I doubt from what you said, then closing it in the method above might be valid. However, since it appears that AcmTableRowLoader is using it in places other than the constructor... I would suggest having the AcmTableRowLoader create and close the stream itself since it knows when it is done with it.

Or in short, close it after you have closed the xmlSource. Hard to tell exactly where / how without more context. Looks like you just jumped the gun.

Answer (score 0):

Try to close the Stream in the Thread that reads from it, when parse() returns the stream can be closed.
If you want to close the stream in another Thread you can have a look at AsyncTask.

Comment: From the discussion it appears that closing **ins** is causing an NPE in **xmlStream**. Not that **ins** is null.

Answer (score 0):

The best practice is to put your entire code into a `try{ ... }catch` block and add a `finally` block where you should close the inputstream.